# Is innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1 means that if commit return ok, the buffer is flush to log?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I write a test program:

1. start a transaction
2. insert 100000 rows into a table
3. commit
4. select count(1) from the table and get 100000 returned
5. use kill -9 to shutdown mysqld thread

then restart, I found that innodb crash recovery happended

Comment: Too many things are in the background for this to be a valid test.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit? It says in part:

> - innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit
>
>   The default value of 1 is required for full ACID compliance. With
>     this value, the contents of the InnoDB log buffer are written out to
>     the log file at each transaction commit and the log file is flushed to
>     disk.

Are you surprised that InnoDB crash recovery runs after you `kill -9` the mysqld process? It's not clear from your question if you're asking if this is normal. It is.